# Can the influence of a different factor on a known effect be analyzed directly?

Tags: interaction, effect-size

If I am trying to analyse wether a known effect is inhibited by another factor, is it a fallacy to analyse the influence of the factor on the effect size directly? I.e. can I just use a statistical test between the effect sizes for different conditions, or do I have to do a full interaction model?

Here is the setup. In each condition I am measuring two variables `X_1` and `X_2`. The difference between the variable `X_1` and `X_2` gives the effect size I am interested in.

Now I also have two conditions `C_1` and `C_2` and my hypothesis is, that the effect size for `C_2` will be smaller than for `C_1`. One way I could test this, is by calculating all the effect sizes in condition `C_1` from the appropriate `X_1` and `X_2` and comparing all these with the effects calculated for `C_2`.

However what I am analysing could also be seen as an interaction effect between the conditions and the factor which went into producing `X_1` and `X_2`. So I could also use an `2x2` interaction model, to see if my conditions have a significant influence on the effect size.

What would be the problem with an direct analysis of the effect size? In the final plot I would like to show only the conditions versus effect sizes, because this will reduce a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you prefer simply to show the difference between the results under c_1 and c_2, but that you have the nagging feeling you "should" develop an interaction model. I have no idea where that feeling is coming from, but, if done well, such a model will tell you not only the magnitude of the difference but also the *p*-value associated with it. In other words, it will tell how rare such a difference would be if condition didn't truly matter, and if chance alone were at work in creating the difference you obtained for your samples. Is such a piece of probabilistic information useful to you, or to the audience for your study?  The answer to that "should" determine whether you run such a test or whether you stick with the descriptive findings.

EDIT:  I'm rethinking my answer after reading your comment and rereading your question.  There is no "factor which went into producing X_1 and X_2" -- the difference score is simply one minus the other, and this doesn't depend on any factor.  I see nothing with which the condition variable can interact.  If you want to run an inferential procedure, the *t*-test is the one, as long as you have looked into its usual assumptions.  There's no "flaw" to it, and there's nothing wrong with plotting 2 difference score means as opposed to 4 pre-differencing means. I think the situation is simpler than you have been envisioning.

Comment: Yes, the p-value is definitely needed. However if I do the analysis directly, for example by doing a t-test on the effect sizes in the two groups, I also would get a p-value. Is this p-value somehow flawed, so that I should avoid using it? The other nagging feeling I have is, that a real plot for the interaction model would need four data points, to fully fit the concept of the test. However I want to reduce this to two data points only. However this is more of an asthetic than a scientific problem.